# Docker Compose v3 Ports issue

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I've started using Docker 17.03.0 to make use of swarm/deploy.

I am wondering if I have stumbled across a bug, or am configuring something incorrectly here.

With a standard `docker-compose up` on our previous, no swarm, setup I was able to expose a port to localhost only (not the outside world).  It seems the same line in the compose file is ignored when I run `docker deploy`.

Has anyone else seen this, and know of what I could be doing wrong here?  Exposing the postgres port to `0.0.0.0` is definitely something I don't want happening.

Relevant lines in docker-compose.yml

```
postgres:
    image: postgres:9.3
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./prod.env
    ports:
        - "127.0.0.1:5432:5432"
```

Old docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.12.5
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.4
 Git commit:   7392c3b
 Built:        Fri Dec 16 02:42:17 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.5
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.4
 Git commit:   7392c3b
 Built:        Fri Dec 16 02:42:17 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Output from `netstat -ano | grep LISTEN`

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
```

New Docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:      17.03.0-ce
 API version:  1.26
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   3a232c8
 Built:        Tue Feb 28 08:01:32 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.0-ce
 API version:  1.26 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   3a232c8
 Built:        Tue Feb 28 08:01:32 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Output from `netstat -ano | grep LISTEN`

```
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      off (0.00/0/0)
```

Which is listening on all interfaces...

Comment: docker services use IPVS to load balance exposed ports to multiple containers underneath, it could be a bug/requirement related to that setup. One question would be why are you exposing the port at all if you don't want anything external connected to it?

Comment: Good question...  I have been using it for database maintenance on the old system (via an ssh tunnel), and noticed the issue when I went to perform a couple of tasks on the new one.  Perhaps there is a better way to do this?  I would love to turn the port of entirely.

Comment: You might be able to connect via the internal network. Swarm containers have two adapters. One on the swarm network and the one used for local communication on the host. I can remember there might be a little bit of manual setup to get in via the local interface but it's possible.